# My Iberia flight was cancelled, what are my options?

Tags: eu, cancellations, ec261, iberia

I am planning to travel from Portugal to Norway in June, and I have booked the return flight from Bergen, Norway to Lisbon, Portugal through Iberia. The booking actually consists of two flights, one from Bergen to Madrid, and then from Madrid to Lisbon.

I have noticed on Iberia's website that the Bergen-Madrid flight has been cancelled and I don't know what I should do. I've checked [this "air passenger's rights" site](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#reimbursement-cancellation-1) and it claims the following:

> The airline must offer you, on a one off basis, a choice between:
>
> 1. the reimbursement of your ticket and, if you have a connecting flight, a return flight to the airport of departure at the earliest
>      opportunity
> 2. re-routing to your final destination at the earliest opportunity or,
> 3. re-routing at a later date at your convenience under comparable transport conditions, subject to the availability of seats.

But I am not sure that I am interpreting it correctly. It seems to me that the airline must offer me the above choices, and that choice number 2 would be an equivalent flight from Bergen to Lisbon approximately on the same date.

**Am I interpreting this correctly ?**

I have filed a complaint on Iberia's website, but their response time is 21 working days, so it will probably take a while before I have a concrete answer from them.

In the meantime **I don't know if I should assume that my trip will still happen and continue planning it, or if I should wait until I have a confirmation from Iberia** that I will indeed be able to travel. I still need to book a car and a hotel, and the more I wait, the more expensive they will get.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Do you mean June? That's five months away. That a single flight in five months time shows as cancelled on a web site may not mean very much.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the choices you posted mostly refer to cancellations on the day of travel ("return to airport of departure"), not five months away. Can you check your booking online on their website? If the flight was indeed canceled, an updated itinerary should be available there...

Comment: I've already checked their website but there's no updated information. The only change is that the cancelled flight no longer shows up there, only the second part, from Madrid to Lisbon.

Comment: For situations like this you should get out the phone and call the airline, rather than email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [International Iberia fight cancelled due to technical issue: what are my rights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96025/international-iberia-fight-cancelled-due-to-technical-issue-what-are-my-rights)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, plan as if the travel goes on as per the flights you were booked on but I would not book thing where you do not get your money back if you do have to cancel.
Most likely you will be offered an alternative that gets you from Lisbon to Bergen and from Bergen to Lisbon around the same time, but if no other flights are available it might be a few days earlier or later.

June is still plenty far away that alternatives will be available, maybe with a stop in an other country, like Germany rather than Spain.